# Range of nonlinear function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'd like to know the range of function $$f(x)=(x^2, x^3)$$
and how to proceed in these problems.

(The domain is $R$ while the codomain is $R^2$.)

What is the image of interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: It should be made more clear from the start what the domain and codomain of $f$ is.  Without specifying further, $f$ appears to be $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ and will take something like $-2$ and map it to $((-2)^2,(-2)^3)=(4,-8)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Good guess! and sorry for the imprecision... so what about the range?

Comment: The "*range*" (also called *image*) of the function is the set of possible outputs.  Notice that all outputs will have something in common.  Is $(9,9)$ a possible output?  What about $(9,20)$?  The answer being, neither of these are possible because it is not of the form $(x^2,x^3)$.  If the first entry of the output is a $9$, the second entry must be a $27$ or a $-27$.  How would you think to try to describe this set in words?  In symbols?  What about if the input is restricted to being in the range $[0,1]$?

Comment: @JMoravitz you exactly told what I still don't catch. I already knew that output variables are always "connected", so the image can't be $R^2$.. it's a smaller subset... But I don't manage exactly writing the relationship...

Comment: @JMoravitz The image is given by the couples  (y, z) where y>0 and z=y^(3/2).. but I don't think this is the answer yet.. Am I wrong?

Comment: $y$ is allowed to be zero, so not quite.  Also, with you writing $z=y^{\frac{3}{2}}$, it is ambiguous whether you mean the principle root or the other possibility.  Note that when $y=9$ you could have $z=27$ or $z=-27$.  It is easier in my opinion not to try to simplify too much as it doesn't really reveal anything extra that is special about the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Given a function $f:A\to B$ (this notation means $A$ is the domain and $B$ is the codomain of the function), the *range* of $f$ is defined as:

$$Range(f)=f(A) = \{b\in B~:~\exists a\in A~\text{such that}~f(a)=b\}$$

In words, the range of $f$ is the set of all elements in the codomain which have a preimage, i.e. some element in the domain, which maps to it.

Some times we can simplify things further, but in this case, the way to write the range is going to look very similar to the basic definition.

For your specific example, we have

$$Range(f)=\{(x^2,x^3)\in\Bbb{R}~:~x\in\Bbb R\}$$

For the range of the specific interval, you have:

$$f([0,1])=\{(x^2,x^3)\in\Bbb{R}~:~x\in[0,1]\}$$

Comment: what about $$Range(f)=\{(y,y^\frac{3}{2})\in\Bbb{R}^2~:~y\in\Bbb R^+ \}$$?

Answer (score 0):

This is a parametrisation of the cubic curve with equation $y^2=x^3$, i.e. $y=\pm\sqrt{x^3}$. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: So what would you write as range?

Comment: The (real) algebraic curve with (implicit) equation $y^2=x^3$.